# Unable to order by column, when copying column's values become NULL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temp table in a stored procedure which is causing me some trouble. The basic symptom that showed up was that it wouldn't let me order by a specific column.

```
-- Mockup table
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `result` (
    col_a INT,
    col_b VARCHAR(100),
    col_c VARCHAR(100),
    col_d VARCHAR(100));

-- Imagine inserting and updating a bunch of data here...

-- And then we select
SELECT
    *
FROM
    result
ORDER BY
    col_b ASC,
    col_c ASC,
    col_d ASC;
```

The above would make MySQL happily blurt out a result set ordered by `col_c` and then `col_d`. No ordering by `col_b` at all.

Tried all possible permutations and concluded that there were two columns that it would always refuse to order by (real names in my actual table being `department` and `userid`, `VARCHAR(100)` and `INT` respectively).

So, tried mucking about with collation and db engine on the temp table but this had no effect. Couldn't find any odd data in either column.

Now this morning I tried making an exact copy of the `result` table which I named `resultCopy` and did the equivalent of (but with the real column names, real table has 15 columns which is a bit much for this example):

```
INSERT INTO `resultCopy` (col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d)
    SELECT col_a, col_b, col_c, col_d
    FROM result;

SELECT
    *
FROM
    resultCopy
ORDER BY
    col_b ASC,
    col_c ASC,
    col_d ASC;
```

The results I got back had only NULL values in both the unsortable columns. Other than that the sort order is exactly the same.

So, my original `result` table has data in it (including in the unsortable columns), when selecting from the table this data is clearly being returned (both in the terminal MySQL client and MySQL Workbench as well as in my application, it's just sorted wrong) but if I try inserting this data into an identical temp table it goes missing.

Oh, and for added fun, if I don't drop the temp table (`result`) at the end of the procedure and run my select query again just after I run the procedure it sorts just fine.

So, does anyone have any idea what's going on here?

MySQL version: 5.1.41-3ubuntu12.10

Comment: this may be because your temporary table doesn't preserves the data before commit.

Comment: Immediately after one of these bizarre operations, especially the `INSERT ... SELECT`, does `SHOW WARNINGS` display anything of interest?

Comment: @eggyal I'm getting a bunch of warnings about `Column 'userid' cannot be null` (nothing about the `department` column though) when checking warnings right after inserting into `resultCopy` from `result`.

Comment: The `userid` column is not defined as `NOT NULL`, just plain `userid INT,` when the table is created. Oh, had another warning at the top. `Unknown table 'result'`. That's kind of odd...

Comment: Tried creating the table as a regular table rather than as a temp table and ran `mysqlcheck` on it. Nothing wrong according to `mysqlcheck`.

Comment: Behavior of the table is the same. Data shows up when selecting from the table but won't sort on two of the columns, when copying data to another table (this one still a temp table) those columns have only NULL values and when selecting from the table outside the procedure it sorts fine.

Comment: Maybe related to [Bug #32868](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=32868)?  After any DDL statement, try the workaround suggested by Shane Bester: "*flush the stored routine cache by doing this: ``CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `tmpview` AS SELECT 1;``*"?

Comment: Well, that seems to relate to altering tables and this procedure doesn't alter any of the tables, just creates and drops them. Tried the workaround though, sadly no result.

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`result\`;` gives me the same statement that I use for creating the table (except it adds `DEFAULT NULL` for every column which isn't specified as `NOT NULL`).